# how to connect core plot graphview to a button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-plot

I am doing a project according to this coreplot tutorial http://www.gilthonwe.com/2012/06/09/stacked-bar-chart-coreplot-ios/#comment-23
actually, it works fine on a uiview, but when I use a modal segue or custom segue to display the view, it won't work, just stop at a point. but push segue works fine.
Can anyone tell me how to use a button(modal segue) to launch the graphview?
Thanks a lot!
Ze

Answer (score 0):

You might try having another view controller with the button and have a segue to the view with the plot. So on pressing the button (associate an action with the button), you can perform the segue.